# Aggregate dataframe to list by sorted column values

Tags: r

I have a matrix of the following form:

```
adj <- matrix(c(2, 3, 335, 337, 6, 7, 10,
                1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3), nrow = 7)

adj
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    1
[2,]    3    1
[3,]  335    1
[4,]  337    1
[5,]    6    3
[6,]    7    3
[7,]   10    3
```

The matrix is sorted first by column 2, next by column 1.
I would want to convert this to an (adjacency) list of the form:

```
[[1]] 2 3 335 337
[[2]] integer(0)
[[3]] 6 7 10
```

I'm recently new to R (and Stack Overflow) and know that the choice
of implementation may drastically increase the speed of computation.
My first naive implementation to perform this task was

```
adj <- lapply(1:(tail(adj, 1)[2]), function(x) {
  as.integer(adj[which(adj[,2] == x), 1])
})
```

which unfortunately does not exploit the knowledge of column 2 being sorted and seems to be quite slow when 'adj' is a large matrix (more specifically, 68.2 Mb), whereas I was able to completely construct the original matrix in a fraction of seconds.

Hence, I was wondering what's a more 'R-friendly' way of implementing such code. (I have mostly been avoiding for loops so far.)

Comment: My recommendation is to convert to data frame and split. i.e. `dd <- data.frame(adj);  split(dd$X1, dd$X2)`

Comment: Try with `library(data.table); dcast(transform(as.data.frame(adj), V2 = factor(V2, levels = 1:3)), V2 ~ rowid(V2), value.var = "V1", drop = FALSE)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `base R` option would be to do `split`.  Create a `list` of length 3 with elements `integer(0)` and then assign the `split` values of first column based on the second column to those elements that are found in second column of 'adj'

```
lst <- setNames(rep(list(integer(0)), 3), 1:3)
lst[unique(adj[,2])] <- split(adj[,1], adj[,2])
lst
#$`1`
#[1]   2   3 335 337

#$`2`
#integer(0)

#$`3`
#[1]  6  7 10
```

Comment: I Thought It had to be a data frame to be able to split. Hence my recommendation to convert to df first. Good to know it works in matrices as well

Comment: I found this direct split to result in the fastest solution. The conversion to a data frame first was somewhat slower, although the final outputted list was similar to my desired results and a lot smaller (17.5 MB instead of 256.2 MB). As I am converting the final list to a graph anyway, I'm opting for the fastest method as the graph uses the same storage for both. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Convert the second column to a factor, `fac`, having all levels and then split the first column on that.  (If `adj[, 2]` were *not* sorted then use `min(adj[, 2])` and `max(adj[, 2])` as the arguments of `seq`.)

```
nr <- nrow(adj)
fac <- factor(adj[, 2], levels = seq(adj[1, 2], adj[nr, 2]))
split(adj[, 1], fac)
```

giving:

```
$`1`
[1]   2   3 335 337

$`2`
numeric(0)

$`3`
[1]  6  7 10
```

Note that if you want integers convert adj to integer first and then run the above code.

```
mode(adj) <- "integer"
```

Comment: Thats smart using a factor here. Much faster than precreating empty integers first and then overwriting. I guess ...